# Как переводить на русский язык термины future/promise?

Tags: терминология, language-lawyer, promise

Как переводят обычно в русскоязычной литературе слова `future` и `promise`?

Comment: Да обычно никак. Так и пишут `future` и `promise`.

Comment: `Promise` вполне можно переводить как "обещание". Хотя в последнее время в IT не очень-то любят переводить термины, даже когда есть адекватный русский термин, соответствующий английскому

Comment: К примеру [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) в русской статье использует английское написание.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вопрос звучит именно "как переводят", а не "как используют" термины, то можно встретить такие варинты переводов:

**promise - обещание**

Пример, "создаём **обещание** выполнить что-то при наступлении такого-то события" - звучит гораздо осмысленнее для русскоговорящего человека, чем "создаём **promise** выполнить..."

Так как речь идёт про терминологию, то скорее всего вместо слова **future** (сущ, прил. будущее) подразумевалось слово **feature**.

**feature** - имеет несколько вариантов перевода: особенность, характеристика, черта, функция, средство и т.п, которые могут по-разному использоваться в зависимости от контекста.

Примеры: key features - основные (ключевые) характеристики; feature logic - логика признаков.

Comment: В этом случае все таки future (будущее) скорей всего подразумевается, т.к. это термин из одной группы с promise.

Comment: Нет, это именно future. И я знаю, как эти слова переводятся с английского. Вопрос был: как переводить? (Допустим, в учебнике.)

Comment: @vladon да так и переводите "будущее", для англоязычных же читателей понятно о каком "future" у них идёт речь.